# Should bash scripts called with --help argument return 0 or not-zero exit code?

Tags: bash, exit-code

Writing a bash script that displays the usage information when called with `--help` argument, what exit code is it recommended to return/exit the script with?

```
$ my_script --help; echo $?
Usage ...
0
```

or

```
$ my_script --help; echo $?
Usage ...
1
```

If there are different opinions, what are the arguments for one or the other options?

- Tools like: `grep` (on MacOS), `man` return a non-zero exit code.
- Tools like: `bash`, `sh`, `vim` return 0 as exit code.

Comment: Zero, because the program ends sucessful

Comment: In bash, exit code `0` is a success. For other values, see [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).

Comment: @Jens Why aren't then tools like `grep`, `man`, `ping` considering `--help` as success?

Comment: grep and man both return 0 with `--help` for me. ping doesn't have a `--help` option, so it fails.

Comment: Which Linux Version do you use?

Comment: "If there are different opinions" ... Uh, you know there are, because you just cited 6 examples of different opinions. Which makes this question pretty clearly off-topic.

Comment: @Flimzy maybe not so "off-topic". The question is what are the good/better practices for writing bash code.

Comment: @cadaniluk see next comment

Comment: @Jens I am using MacOS but if there is an obvious trend on Linux that MacOS is not respecting, please give an answer such that this topic is then visible for other. My scripts I write on Mac should later work on Linux as well.

Comment: I think re-wording this to "What are the reasons to exit with a non-0 status for '--help'?" would be on-topic. By focusing only on one option, it doesn't put the two up against each other, and doesn't ask for a "right" answer. Then with the input learned, you can decide what to do in your programs. But as it is currently worded, it's very clearly primarily opinion based (and asking for opposing and supporting opinions doesn't fix that).

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay done

Comment: @Flimzy maybe asking it that way, would already bias people in one direction or even more offend people that don't believe that is correct. Like this, I, as well as everyone who reads this, can learn what the alternatives are and if someone gives an answer with links to good resources, I think this question would have a good value. Plus that I searched already 15 minutes for a similar topic and it seems like it is not so often addressed.

Comment: It would bias the answers (aka focus them), by design. And if someone is offended by asking for the reasons for something, that's their problem, and not an excuse for posing opinion-based questions.

Comment: And I don't dispute the value of this question... I think it's fundamentally a good question. It just needs to be worded in a constructive, and on-topic way. Asking "which is best?" is neither. Understanding the reasons for one or the other, or both, is constructive, and not opinion-based.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The output should go to `stdout` and the script should return 0 unless there was an IO error. (The user requested a help screen and you delivered. The operation was a success.)

If you output the same help screen as a response to incorrect use, output it to `stderr` and fail (=exit with a nonzero).
(The user tried to do something but they did it wrong — the operation failed and you're giving them a hint via `stderr` (because on `stdout`, they might well be expecting something else) as to how they might do it right.)

I think these are good and reasonable practices, and most good CLI tools I've seen follow them.
(This includes my Linux Mint's `grep`, `man`, and `ping`, with the caveat that `ping` complains of not having a help option, but it does so consistently with the 2nd paragraph of this advice.)

Answer (score 2):

Zero is the correct return code, because the command runs successful which is the meaning of the return code 0.